# Automatic -1 suffix being added to the permalinks of a page when the page does not exist

Tags: permalinks

I have a really strange problem with a -1 suffix being added to a permalink on a page im trying to create which is getting very frustrating. Its specifically a page titled event, each time i try to add the new page titled event the suffix -1 gets added.

I have checked every single possible post, page, category, tag in every single post type and page too. I have gone to the URL and im getting a 404 page not found error. I have tried to rewrite the links numerous times in settings. I have checked the trash and drafts for any pages and posts too.

I have even downloaded a plugin named "Remove Old Slugs" which did not find the 'event'.

Has anyone else come aross this problem before? The usual rewrite permalinks usually works, but this time it really has not.

Any help rearding this would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Strange.If you have access to the database you can manually find and delete the post/page etc that reserve the slug. Do you have a custom post called event?

Comment: odd one, just to check, does a folder exist at the location of the url? domain.tld/event or whatever?!

Comment: Problem Solved: It was Wordpress being strange. I had to delete the original page (for example: /events) and then delete the -1 suffix pages (for example: events-1),  > empty trash and recreate the pages.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had near enough the exact same problem and I'm in the middle of fixing it.

In my case it's an inability to use the slug 'events' as any attempt redirects to an archive page with all archive results for events, for which I have a custom post type in fact.

I've tried using a custom events page, I've tried using an events template applied to a normal wordpress page and only the permalink that I don't want to use will work.

I've had this issue before with other slug names and I believe that 'events' is a slug reserved either by WordPress or by a plugin and therefore the only way I could fix it was to change the slug to 'our-events' and then set up a redirect for anyone for anyone trying to use the url with /events or /events.php

I hope this helps?

If you've already found a solution that's different then maybe you could share it with me as I'd be interested to find out alternative solutions to this?

Thanks - Rob